# Finding the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am given $A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix} $ and B = $ \begin{pmatrix}
e & f\\ 
g & h
\end{pmatrix}$ whose elements are non-zero reals.

> If $BA = I$, where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and $D$ is the value of the determinant of $B$, then find the value of $D$

Assume that four options are given for the correct answer (which is $\frac{d}{e}$) and only one is correct. How can I find the correct answer quickly?

**ADDED:**

The answer suggested in my module is $\frac{d}{e}$, so I am suppose to derive to that point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The determinant of $B$ is given by $eh-gf$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#2-by-2_matrices)). Presumably, the question is asking you to describe this quantity in terms of $a,b,c,d$. In that case, here are some facts you can combine to find the answer:

- $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ for all matrices $X$ and $Y$
- $\det(I)=1$
- $\det(A)=ad-bc$

These facts together show that $D=\det(B)=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$. Now note that the entries of $B=A^{-1}$, in terms of the entries of $A$, are (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inversion#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices))
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{d}{ad-bc}\,\,\,\, & \frac{-b}{ad-bc}\\ \stackrel{\vphantom{g}}{\frac{-a}{ad-bc}}\,\,\,\, & \frac{c}{ad-bc}\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus, $\displaystyle e=\frac{d}{ad-bc}$, so that $\displaystyle\frac{d}{e}=ad-bc$, which is wrong. The correct answer is $\displaystyle\frac{e}{d}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$.

Comment: I am aware of this,but I can't see how these is going to help me here :(

Comment: By the first fact, $\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)$. Because $BA=I$, we have... do you see the rest?

Comment: Yes,but the answer is $\frac{d}{e}$ ?!

Comment: No... you want an answer that depends on $a,b,c,$ and $d$. Putting our three facts together, $$1=\det(I)=\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)=\det(B)\cdot(ad-bc)$$
Now divide.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles:I think you don't get me,the answer suggested in my modules is $\frac{d}{e}$ how to reduce to that?

Comment: @Zev:But ain't the elements are defined to be non-zero reals?

Comment: @Tretwick: I've added to my answer.

Comment: You can't "reduce to" $d/e$ because that answer is wrong.  Try an example: $A = \left(\matrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 3\cr}\right)$, 
$B = \left(\matrix{3/5 & -1/5\cr -1/5 & 2/5\cr}\right)$, 
$D = 1/5 = e/d \ne d/e$.  Or was $D$ supposed to be the determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\: $ Multiplicative maps $\rm\:d\:$ preserve products so inverses $\rm\ A\:B = 1\ \Rightarrow\ d(A)\:d(B) = d(1) = 1\:.\ $

Note: $\rm\ 1^2 = 1\ \Rightarrow\ d(1)^2 = d(1)\ $ so $\rm\ d(1) = 1\ $ if the target is a domain and $\rm\ d\not\equiv 0\:.$